# Calculate elevation (view) angle with incidence angle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I want to calculate the elevation (view) angle of a satellite using the incidence angle.[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xvTw.jpg)

On this site there is a tool which you can use to calculate it but without description.

https://www.intelligence-airbusds.com/en/8719-angle-conversion

Does any body have an idea how I could do that? 
Additionally I have the satellite position and the earth is an ellipsoid.

Comment: I've added a bounty to this question. I presume this was Pleiades imagery you were working with, which is my case. With that imagery, there is the following metadata provided: acquisition time, azimuth, incidence, illumination(sun) azimuth, illumination(sun) elevation, along track incidence, and across track incidence.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see the drawing is following:

[image]